# How to properly run the streamingRecognize() function provided by google cloud speech api

Tags: node.js, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I have some issue with the `streamingRecognize()` function to stream speech to text.

When I run, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: 
speechClient.streamingRecognize is not a function
```

When I try accessing it through the api object of my speechClient instance, I get this error as response:

```
google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeRequest#0 is not a field:
undefined
```

This is my code:

```
console.log('Listenning started')        
document.getElementById("speak-btn").value = "Stop";

// retrieve settings
console.log("Retrieve audio and language settings...")
database.existSettingsRecord({}, (settingsRecord) => {             

    // The BCP-47 language code to use, e.g. 'en-US'
    const languageCode = settingsRecord.language; //'en-US';

    // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
    const nathProjectId = 'protocol-recorder-201707';

    // Instantiates a client
    const speechClient = Speech({
        projectId: nathProjectId,
        keyFilename: './rsc/credentials/spr-426ec2968cf6.json'
    });

    // The encoding of the audio file, e.g. 'LINEAR16'
    const encoding = 'LINEAR16';

    // The sample rate of the audio file in hertz, e.g. 16000
    const sampleRateHertz = 16000;          

    const request = {
        config: {
            encoding: encoding,
            sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
            languageCode: languageCode
            },  
        interimResults: false // If you want interim results, set this to true
    };

    // Create a recognize stream           
    var notes = '';  
    console.log('crate the recognize Stream object to be piped..')
    //const recognizeStream = speechClient.createRecognizeStream(request)
    console.log("speechClient : ",speechClient)
    console.log("grpc : ",grpc)
    const recognizeStream = speechClient.streamingRecognize(request)
        .on('error', console.error)
        .on('data', (response) => {
            //process.stdout.write(response.results)   
            process.stdout.write(
                (response.results[0] && response.results[0].alternatives[0])
                ? `Transcription: ${response.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
                : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`);                  

            notes = document.getElementById("notes").value;  
            notes = notes + response.results;
            document.getElementById("notes").value =  notes;
        });

    // Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
    console.log('Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API..')
    record.start({
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        threshold: 0,
        // Other options, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16#options
        verbose: true,
        recordProgram: 'sox', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
        silence: '1.0',
        device : settingsRecord.audio_input
    })
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(recognizeStream);
```

I am using :

- Win 10
- Node js 7.10.0
- sox 14.4.2

Thanks for any help on that issues!

Comment: Looking at the API, the function name should be: `StreamingRecognize` .. (capital S).

Comment: I get the same erro using capital S : Uncaught TypeError: speechClient.StreamingRecognize is not a function

Comment: This is the way i m trying accessing it through the Speech.api object: const recognizeStream = speechClient.api.Speech._streamingRecognize(request)

Comment: Ok. I simply found that [reference here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/streaming-recognize). I've never worked with the API, but I simply checked the function name use. It seems that there should be a `Create()` call before that function too, based on the example at that link?

Comment: Thank you @PaulT. for your interest !  May be are you referring to the createReadStream() method call on fs object ? If so, it is noteworthy that this particular method is called in the streamming from a local audio file, however I am using the other example where the streaming is base on an audio input (microphone inmy case)... There are two examples in that link, and it is precisely there that I catch what I have implemented in the code above there... :-)

Comment: Oh I see. What I originally looked at (for the capital S) was C# code, so I missed the tab to nodejs, so yes, you appear to have the same code. I've reached the limit of my basic API checks to be helpful here, as I've not used this API as mentioned previously. However, others seem to have the [same trouble](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/issues/332) (scroll to the bottom)  One entry that looks a little different there is: `const recognizeStream = speechClient.api.Speech._streamingRecognize(request)`

Comment: You should follow the code examples given at the first place